# How many 3-digit numbers whose sum of digit(s) is/are 9 or multiples of 9?

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

Challenging question from TIMO 2018 Secondary 3 (Thailand Mathematical Olympiad):              How many $3$-digit numbers whose sum of digit(s) is/are $9$ or multiples of $9$ ?

Comment: What have you done so far? Please show your working. Have you tried to identify any pattern in the numbers which have sum of digits as multiples of nine?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: think of the divisibility rule for $9$.

Answer (score 0):

If the sum of the digits of a number is divisible by $9$ then the number is itself divisible by $9$. Hence just find the numbers divisible by $9$ between $99$ and $1000$.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think it's a challenging problem? Find the number of solutions of $x+y+z= 9k$ where k= 1,2,3. Then we're done. Finding integer solutions for this kinda equation is a routine combi problem. I don't see anything challenging here. Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

The sum of the digits of $n$ is a multiple of $9$ if and only if $n$ is a  multiple of $9$. Hence, the number of $n$ is just the number of $3$-digit multiples of $9$. That will be $(999-102)/3+1=\boxed{300}$.